# Ati amd radeon hd 4350 graphics driver

Tags: ati, radeon

i have card radeon ati hd 4350 and have problem with install drivers to this card. somebody know how do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AMD Ati Radeon HD 4870 Drivers on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/471609/amd-ati-radeon-hd-4870-drivers-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your graphics card is supported by Ubuntu, here's how to install the proprietary drivers.

Click the Unity menu button and type "Additional Drivers", and then click the icon labeled as such.
[image: Menu search]

When the window opens, if your card is supported, it will list available proprietary drivers.  Just highlight the latest one, or the one marked as tested, and click "Apply Changes" then reboot.
[image: Drivers window]

However, I don't think your card is supported.  I have a Radeon HD 4200 and it's not supported any more.  The problem is that most of the newer, supported versions of Ubuntu use an updated version of the Xorg display server, and AMD has stopped supporting its older cards in newer versions of the driver that are packaged with Ubuntu, and the older drivers don't work with the new Xorg server so you can't just go get those and use them.  The only way to get proprietary driver support without buying one of the newer, supported cards is to downgrade several versions of Ubuntu.

I just confirmed, your card is not supported.  I just went and downloaded the deb file for the proprietary drivers and dug through the documentation, and this is what I found.

Quote: "The AMD Proprietary Linux driver currently supports RADEON 8500 and later, as well as FireGL 8700 and later products. We do not currently plan to include support for any products earlier than this."

Answer (score 0):

Search the dash for Additional drivers. You should find that there are a couple of options listed to install drivers. Experiment to find out which suits the best for you.

*Alternately, as far as I have heard, the AMD official binaries are better than all the other alternatives. So, you are better off downloading from the official website and installing them*.